# Bench spring broken at 90' curve

Tags: seat

Mid 70's Chevy truck bench seat.

Drivers side spring is broken at the 90 degree CURVED portion of the spring and don't have any welding tools:
[image]

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfW2K3_Hd18), he uses cable clamps (Ferrules) to re-connect broken springs.

However, don't see how it would work on the 90 degree curve (unless there are curved ferrules) ?

In [this post](http://www.slantsix.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22163&sid=b4e3b72559a6ed89fcc345a3b262159c), he used fuel lines to connect the springs at the curves.

Is this recommended and will it hold solid ?

Any other ideas ?

Also, after the spring is fixed, is there a way to firm up the entire length of the elevated spring that runs along the drivers side of the bench (as the passenger side feels firmer in general):
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You could try a short piece of steel brake or fuel line. Then crimp, clamp or epoxy it in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I realize this is on a curve, I like the idea of using a ferrule to clamp them into place together. I think the two ends are long enough to accept the ferrule with it keeping them in place. It really doesn't matter if they line up perfectly, the idea is to keep them together so there is mutual support between the two ends. The ferrule should do the job for you. Here is a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image]

You can get these in many different sizes and they can be found at just about any hardware store, including the big box stores.

The way to use it is just insert the two ends, one into each end of the ferrule, then using a pair of Vice Grips, clamp it down. Once it is clamped, it's secure and shouldn't come apart. Just ensure you get the ends of the springs and wedged into the ferrule the best you can and you should be golden.

The idea came from [this video](https://youtu.be/nfW2K3_Hd18) in case you'd like to see exactly what I'm talking about. You'll see the springs he's doing in this video are curved, so should not be an issue.

If you feel the two ends won't come together correctly, try cutting the two sharp ends off, then bending an angle in the spring a ways back, keeping the flat parts of the spring in the same plane. Bring the two ends together and then attach the ferrule. Again, the real thing here is for the two ends to provide mutual support to each other.

Comment: Added a ferrule, still had to bend the spring a little to make sure more of it went into the ferrule, but was lucky because I could take the small part of the broken spring out and bend it with the vice and hammer. So far it looks like it is working. Had to drive all over town to find the tool to crimp it.

Comment: @P.S. - Glad it looks like it's working ... I would have thought a pair of Vice-Grips would have done the trick. They can put a nasty clamp on things!